# Permission denied for view beyond its own schema

Tags: postgresql, permissions, schema, view

There are two schemes `rohdaten_fiat` and `staging_fiat`. I have created a view in the latter one based on the first one.

```
CREATE VIEW staging_fiat.udz_odx_dtcs AS
SELECT * FROM rohdaten_fiat.udz_odx_relational_dtcs;
```

While keeping the database connection alive I can access the view, e. g.

```
SELECT * FROM staging_fiat.udz_odx_dtcs;
```

It runs under the following parameters:

```
SELECT current_user, current_setting('search_path'::text) AS search_path
     , relowner::regrole, relnamespace::regnamespace, relname, relacl
     , pg_get_viewdef(c.oid) AS view_definition
FROM   pg_class c
WHERE  relname = 'udz_odx_dtcs' OR relname = 'udz_odx_relational_dtcs';
```

See: https://pastebin.com/Hn7jAUat

However, **after closing the connection and reconnect to the database**, I can not:

```
SELECT * FROM staging_fiat.udz_odx_dtcs;
```

> ```
> ERROR:  permission denied for relation view
> ```

The environmental parameters are the same (see https://pastebin.com/Hn7jAUat). Curiously, I can execute the query of the view manually:

```
SELECT * FROM rohdaten_fiat.udz_odx_relational_dtcs;
```

Only the view does not work. Where get the permissions lost? And why?

It's PostgreSQL 10.12. The connection including the `search_path` is absolutely identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To diagnose, inspect the output of this query before and after reconnecting in your question:

```
SELECT current_user, current_setting('search_path'::text) AS search_path
     , relowner::regrole, relnamespace::regnamespace, relname, relacl
     , pg_get_viewdef(c.oid) AS view_definition
FROM   pg_class c
WHERE  relname = 'view'  -- actual view name
OR    (relname = 'table' AND relnamespace = 'schema1');   -- actual table & schema name
```

You should get two or more rows each time. I omitted the schema of the view on purpose to see whether there might be others with the same name.

Oh, and make sure, your transaction is committed. Read the manual [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-begin.html#id-1.9.3.47.5).

This is not a direct answer, but it should enable you to get your answer.

Comment: Thanks to this query, I was finally able to identify a background script which was setting the `relowner` and `relacl` of the view to a role with permissions only within the schema `staging_fiat`. Thus, it's working now. Thank you!